# call webservice and redirect to next page without waiting using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services

I have a very time consuming functionality to perform. I want to call the function and redirect to next page with out waiting for the result of function call, i am doing it by calling a webservice form jquery as follow right now:

```
function InitiateService(option) {   
 $.ajax({
    url: "WebserviceTrigger.aspx?option=" + option,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {             
    window.location = "BroadCast.aspx";
    }
});
```

but this way it waits for the result and then redirect to next page. I want to redirect to next page straight away after calling the service. How can i do this? 
thanks in advance

Comment: It's dangerous for calling script and redirect. It will often not work properly

Comment: how do you think to handle the situation?

Comment: You should wait for the result and then call the redirect or maybe open in new window

Answer (score 2):

Move the redirect outside your success in this case once it has fired Ajax, control will execute your redirect location, it wont wait for ajax request to complete.

```
function InitiateService(option) {   
     $.ajax({
        url: "WebserviceTrigger.aspx?option=" + option,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {             

        }
    });

    window.location = "BroadCast.aspx"; // move it outside success
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. i already have tried it, it redirects to BraodCast.aspx page but it shows the page loading till the process doesn't complete.

Comment: thats your browser default mechanism, till them time it is doing something in background it will show you loading symbol, but I assume your redirect would be getting completed

Answer (score 0):

You can use `async` option of ajax request to make your code synchronous. By default it will be `true`. You can just make it to `false`. `'async':false`

```
function InitiateService(option) {   
     $.ajax({
        url: "WebserviceTrigger.aspx?option=" + option,
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        dataType: "html",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {             

        }
    });
```

Comment: where to place this? page directive or webservice call?

Comment: async = false means this is a synchronous call, first complete this and then proceed which is against what OP is looking for, also aynch = false will make your subsequent calls wait only in Firefox, Chrome doesnt work in IE